# wordpress drop down menu are not properly styled as they are inheriting style from parent . want to give custom background to drop downs

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

this is my code for navigation ----->

```
$main = array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' , 'link_before'     => '<span>',
'link_after'      => '</span>','container' => '',
'items_wrap' => '%3$s',


 );


wp_nav_menu( $main );
```

i am applying span tag to style li items . what i actually want to do is that span tag should only be applied to main menu (depth = 1 in hierarchy ) and not to its sub menus(in drop down)

```
html ouptut is something like 

<ul class=main>

<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/samplesite/?page_id=19"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li> >
<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/samplesite/?page_id=19"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li> >

<ul class ="sub=menu" >

<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/samplesite/?page_id=19"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li> >
    </ul>
<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/samplesite/?page_id=19"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li> >
 </ul>
```

i dont want span tag in sub-menu class li items, is there a way to do this .?

Comment: Try using the > operator. For example ul.main > li > ul{background: red;}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style the sub-menu differently, the identifier you should be using is `.sub-menu` but depending on the theme you are using, the author for the theme might have styled either the UL, LI, or A of the menu. Find that out from style.css and write your code for the same identifier.

eg. if style.css contains something like this

```
.menu li a { background: #fff; }
```

then you'll need to write this line:

```
.sub-menu { background: #888; }
```

It's also a good practice to use `background` if the theme's style used 'background', and 'background-color' if the theme's style used `background-color`.